# How to copy files to a folder that need admin rights?

Tags: file-permissions, administrator

I'm using Windows 10 and I need to copy some files to a folder that asks for administrator permission. Without booting to a live linux USB is it possible to perform this on the running system and the standard user logged on?

Comment: You should ask yourself if this is something you really want to do. It looks as though you don't have admin privileges, so I assume it is not your own machine. Maybe you should ask the owner to modify the filesystem privileges, or copy the files for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without having the administrator's password. If you use Explorer to copy files to a protected folder, it will ask for those.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In that case, can I boot into Linux or Windows on the go and change the permissions for that folder? Would those permissions be reflected on the OS once I booted as a normal user?

Comment: @SilvaV I don't know. You might [ask](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) a separate question about that